# Is the question "Should Elohim in Hebrew be translated into Allah?" on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic

The question https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11459/3487 doesn't seem to be have anything to do with Islam and is about the Hebrew language. And how a particular Arabic word translated into Hebrew.

Is it off-topic?

Comment: Hei, looks like I am the one asking that question. So we have a political issue that is obviously very related to islam. However, that's not on topic as if islam has nothing to do with it. I don't know. I feel like I am being stone walled. We have a religion with so many "problems". People either use the religions to justify so many things. And yet, we got this attitude as if this has nothing to do with "the religion".

Answer (score 2):

While the linked article brings up some interesting issues, questions on which would probably be constructive and on-topic, as phrased OP's question is...confusing.

The article in the question is about issues surrounding translation of the Hebrew "Elohim" into the *Malay* word "Allah" (which would most probably be a loanword from Arabic).  The question, however, does not appear to be about that.

It appears to be asking three distinct questions:

- **Is the Hebrew "Eloah" cognate to the Arabic "Ilah"?** You might be able to argue this is on-topic, but it's very close to the line of "Arabic Language that doesn't directly relate to the teachings of Islam"
- **What is the Hebrew term for "Allah"?** Most likely off-topic, as it pertains to the Hebrew language rather than Islam.  But again, it's very close to the line as it would be very relevant in translation of Islamic literature.
- **Should translators of the bible uses Ilah, Eloah, Dewa or Deva instead?** This one is just confusing...Ilah is Arabic, Eloah is Hebrew, and Dewa/Deva are, as best I can tell, Sanskrit.  Not only is this unclear, but the only reason that I can see it being remotely on-topic is due to the linked article (which is regarding a government policy on translating the Bible into *Malay*). It seriously needs work to show that it's actually something that is relevant to this site.

While the three questions are at least tangentially related, as they're all regarding translation of God's name, it's unclear what's really being *asked*.  It could possibly be moulded into something on-topic and answerable by focussing on one particular aspect of the question, but for now it should probably just be closed as unclear.